# Oracle AQ performance tuning

Tags: java, database, oracle, jms, oracle-aq

I am using oracle database [11.2] with advanced queuing (AQ) w/ java JMS API. 
My current oracle setup is default settings, with no additional tuning parameters.
High level architecture:

***Database enqueue message into persistent queue (sorted by priority)***

```
EXEC DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (queue_table => 'order_queue_table', queue_payload_type => 'aqadm.order_message_t', sort_list=>'PRIORITY,ENQ_TIME'); 
EXEC DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (queue_name => 'order_queue', queue_table => 'order_queue_table'); 
EXEC DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (queue_name => 'order_queue');
```

***Java JMS consumer is dequeue messages with 3 concurrent threads.***

Everything is works great! and happy scenario, as long as messages in the queue @10K. 
As soon as messages in queue **doubles** or triples ***dequeue*** performance goes significantly down!!!.

I followed following link
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28420/perform.htm

Any suggestions on performance tuning on IO and AQ?

Answer (score 3):

I see this is old, but I'll give it a shot.  The fact that it runs well with a small(er) number of messages in the queue but poorly with a large(r) number of messages leads me to believe the issue may be in the optimizer statistics for the underlying queue tables and IOTs.

From the [11gR2 Oracle Advanced Queuing User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/perform.htm#sthref434):

> Ensure that statistics are being gathered so that the optimal query
>   plans for retrieving messages are being chosen. By default, queue
>   tables are locked out from automatic gathering of statistics. The
>   recommended use is to gather statistics with a representative queue
>   message load and lock them.

There are several other possibilities, including tuning (or not-tuning) `AQ_TM_PROCESSES` and using ASSM, but without more about your database environment, it's hard to suggest fixes, or even know if that's the problem.